# change year field in Interbase

Tags: database, date, interbase

I have a table with some rows showing the wrong year date. The format of the date is: `MM/DD/YYYY`, but it is showing the year as `1933` instead of `2011`.

How do I change the year with SQL in Interbase? I found I could do a `CDATE` with others databases, but I couldn't find an equivalent on Interbase.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines might work. Assumes that all dates in 1933 need to be updated. CAST(), EXTRACT(), and the concatenation operator ('||') are standard SQL.

```
UPDATE yourtablename
SET date_column = 
  CAST('2011-' || 
        EXTRACT(month from date_column) || '-' || 
        EXTRACT(day from date_column)  as DATE)
WHERE date_column BETWEEN '1933-01-01' and '1933-12-31'
```

Odds are good that if you don't have a CHECK constraint on that column, more 1933 dates will show up sooner or later.